# Google marker is in top left corner

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The marker on the map of my website (www.xeryon.com) is on the right Lat/Long location. However, the marker is positioned in the top left corner of the canvas instead in the centre. When the page is reloaded, the marker is in the centre op the canvas. This issue started when I added the function 'loadpage' to my site (this adds a timeout to my page). How can I change to code to ensure that the marker is always in the centre of the canvas?

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="images/logo_x_transparent.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link href="images/logo_x_transparent.ico" rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no" name="viewport">
<title>XERYON - Experts in Piezo and Precision technology.</title>
<link href="products/default.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="stylesheet/normaliz.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="stylesheet/960.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="stylesheet/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="stylesheet/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.stellar.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--moves the background position-->
<script src="js/jquery.waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            jQuery("a[data-gal^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                social_tools: ''
            });
        });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar;
function loadpage() {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 500);
}
function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap(){
    myVar = setTimeout(loadmap, 1000);
}
function loadmap(){
var myOptions = {zoom:10,scrollwheel:false,styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#d3d3d3"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"color":"#808080"},{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#b3b3b3"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"weight":1.8}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#d7d7d7"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ebebeb"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#a7a7a7"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#efefef"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#696969"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#737373"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#d6d6d6"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#dadada"}]}],
center:new google.maps.LatLng(50.84934800000001,4.735665199999971),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.84934800000001,4.735665199999971),icon:'http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/8BFA02/'});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Xeryon</strong><br>Interleuvenlaan 62, Leuven<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadpage()" style="margin: 0;">
<div class="grid_12" id="loader">
</div>
<div id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
<!-- Google maps start -->
<script async="" defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCVV-HH7g0RyA0hsXUkXWFZ1R09FOvBwiU&amp;callback=initMap">
</script>
<div style=" height: 350px; width: 100%;">
    <div id="gmap_canvas" style="height: 350px; width: 100%;">
    </div>  
    <style>
    #gmap_canvas img {
max-width: none!important;
background: none!important;}
</style>
</div>
<!-- Google maps end-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Putting all your Google Maps related code into two huge long lines probably isn't the best if you want help with it - just my opinion

Comment: Upper left hand corner is a symptom of not having a size for the map div.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Call `map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(50.849348, 4.7356652))` after `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` (set the map center *after* the map div's size is established by the API):

```
function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(50.849348, 4.7356652));
}
```